# Playwright for Java does not currently provide a built-in method to prevent auto-closing the browser window, so how to handle it?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

When there is an element not found or any other exception, it will be very advantageous, if the browser window stays open However  it's auto-closing. I tired with

Browser browser = browserType.launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHandleSIGINT(false));

but no avail. Is there a pragmatic way to handle this in Java with playwright 1.33.0?

```
import com.microsoft.playwright.Browser;
import com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserType;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Page;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Basic {

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();
        Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new 
        BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false).setHandleSIGINT(false));
        Page page = browser.newPage();
        page.navigate("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
        page.click("//a[contains(@href, '/hovers')]");
         page.click("//a[contains(@href, '/failme')]");
        // Prevent the browser from closing.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this at the end of your test where you want to stop/pause:

```
page.pause()
```

I use it inside my tearDown() method when needed as the following:

```
@AfterTest
protected void tearDown() {
    //page.context().browser().close(); //<-- this one didn't work for me
    page.pause(); // <-- this one worked!
}
```

I am using Playwright 1.40.0